# Jquery Smooth scrollToElement offset

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have made the scrollingHotSpot left and right areas nontransparent which now means that when I load the page, the first image is cut off to the left. The same problem happens when I use the scrollToElement function.

To fix the first image being cut off I used this, which works fine:

```
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img{
padding: 0 30 0 30;} //as my scrollinghotspots are 30px wide
```

My scrollToElement image still gets cut off to the left though:

```
$("#jumpToPrint").click(function () {
        $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("scrollToElement", "id", "imgPrint");
    });
```

Tried using the following but it didn't fix the problem:

```
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("scrollToElement", "id", "imgPrint").offset().left - 30;
```

Greatly appreciate any help, cheers!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your html. You should make an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `min-width` of your hotspots is 75px, it looks like it's ignoring the 30px you set for them. Because of this, 30px isn't enough padding for your images. It should work with `padding: 0 75px` or by setting the `min-width` of `.scrollinghotspotleft` and `.scrollinghotspotright` to 30px.

Comment: The only problem I have now is that the padding is too large between each image. I could make the scrollinghotspotleft and right smaller (as you've suggested) so I can bring the padding down, but that makes the hotspot area too small. I want to keep it at 75px but not have to have the padding so large between images. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might try wrapping each of your "panes" in a div and set the padding on the div instead of the images `<div id="0Online"><img src... /><img src... /></div>`. Also, you probably only need padding on the left side. Other than that, you might be able to find some option in the smoothdivscroll plugin you're using to show the controls outside the content instead of overlapping.